# Is there any way for calling onReceive?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

How do i call my onReceive from onCreate?                                                                       I do not want to register this receiver in my manifest.                                Is there any workaround?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Animation = findViewById(R.id.shadow_candy);
    mTimer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    BA = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    if (!BA.isEnabled()) {
        Intent turnOn = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(turnOn, 0);
    }
    // ...
    IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
    IntentFilter filter2 = new IntentFilter(
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECT_REQUESTED);
    IntentFilter filter3 = new IntentFilter(
            BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED);
    this.registerReceiver(BTReceiver, filter1);
    this.registerReceiver(BTReceiver, filter2);
    this.registerReceiver(BTReceiver, filter3);
}

// The BroadcastReceiver that listens for bluetooth broadcasts
private final BroadcastReceiver BTReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            // Do something if connected
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BT Connected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // change lower button
            findViewById(R.id.connect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.connected).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // change upper button
            stopfinding();
            findViewById(R.id.find_me).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.disconnect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            // call my endless glowing animation loop
            method1();
        } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED.equals(action)) {
            // Do something if disconnected
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BT Disconnected",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // change lower button
            findViewById(R.id.connect).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.connected).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // change upper button
            findViewById(R.id.find_me).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById(R.id.disconnect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            // end animation
            findViewById(R.id.shadow_candy).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
        }
        // else if...
    }
};
```

I have tried this already, but doesn't work

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Comment: theres no way to call the onReceive as this was need to register first in manifest and onResume.

Comment: ah thanks, could you provide a snippet for the manifest part?

Comment: BTW i don't think it needs to register, but it needs a manifest tag in order to trigger from onClick

Comment: give any of the action registered in the manifest to the broadcast like this,intent.setAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);

Answer (score 0):

Your intent is sending to nothing.

```
/**
 * Create an empty intent.
 */
public Intent() {
}
```

It has no source (context), no destination, no action. so i think it can't be received.

To fix it, use another constructor of Intent class:

[Intent with Action](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(java.lang.String))

```
public Intent(String action)
```

[Intent with destination](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E))

```
public Intent(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried this already, but doesn't work

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

when you send a broadcast receiver you should specify intent filter

```
IntentFilter filter1 = new IntentFilter(
        BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);
Intent intent = new Intent(filter1);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

or

```
Intent intent = new Intent("my_intent_filter");
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

then register your receiver with specified intent filter

```
this.registerReceiver(BTReceiver, filter1);
```

or

```
this.registerReceiver(BTReceiver, "my_intent_filter");
```